# Get rows and column count on div hover HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to generate table code based on div hover count, that means I have number of divisions like table rows and cells on hover of those I need to get count like 7*5 (means 7 rows 5 columns).

For more details please see below Image

[image]

How can I get that 7x5 based on position of hover div.

I am attaching general code([**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/5ck7w2mt/)) please improve this with JavaScript.

```css
.row{
  margin-bottom:5px;  
}
.cell{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
.row:hover .cell:hover{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDivision">
   <div class="firstrow row">
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
     <div class="secondrow row">
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
   <div class="thirdrow row">
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Value">
    <span id="noOfRow">n</span>
    &nbsp;x&nbsp;
    <span id="noOfColumns">n</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried something for that ?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma: I need to know how to do this, because I don't have any idea on this type of implementation. can you explain me how to implement this

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/5ck7w2mt/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the jquery `index()` function to get the position of the element

try:

```
$('.cell').on('hover',function(){
$('#noOfRow').text(parseInt($(this).parent('.row').index())+1);
    $('#noOfColumns').text(parseInt($(this).index())+1);
});
```

or

```
$('.cell').hover(function(){
$('#noOfRow').text(parseInt($(this).parent('.row').index())+1);
    $('#noOfColumns').text(parseInt($(this).index())+1);
});
```

or with background:

```
$('.cell').hover(function(){
    $('.cell').css({background:'#fff'});
    for (var j = 0;j <= parseInt($(this).parent('.row').index());j++ ) {
    for (var i = 0;i <= parseInt($(this).index());i++ ) {


    $(this).parents('.MainDivision').find('.row').eq(j).find('.cell').eq(i).css({background:'green'});
        }
    }
$('#noOfRow').text(parseInt($(this).parent('.row').index())+1);
    $('#noOfColumns').text(parseInt($(this).index())+1);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ck7w2mt/8/

Comment: Its showing out put but when 1 x 2 result came we need to highlight 2 cells in first row, as well as when 2 x 2 we need to highlight 2 cells in first row and 2 cells in second row. can you help me.

Comment: this is a different question first accept this one and create a new question and we will answer that one

Comment: Its working only with jquery1.7.2 . In latest it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for this latest fiddle.

Comment: Sorry man I didn't see updated fiddle . Now its working fine Thanks.